# VB.net: Simulating keystrokes with codes IN WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, keystroke

I want to dynamically refresh my screen on textbox change. I want to do it with simulating the 'Enter' keystroke on textbox_change, *but I can't find a way to do it IN WPF with VB.net*. Please help!

Comment: You might just need to move the code inside the textbox_change to a separate method and just call that method instead.

Comment: Hi i cannot do that as my code will break with an system.format error. And i have to check if the textboxes are only integers, if not it will not allow further procedure so I think it will be better sending keystrokes to enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I just found the answer, `Button2_Click(Sender, e)` in textbox_change. Perfect solution!